# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 21

Tags: python

```
date = '11/26/2021'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")

print(date_time_obj)
```

it shows the error 'ValueError: unconverted data remains: 21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%Y` to match [*year with century as a decimal number*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> date = '11/26/2021'
>>> datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 26, 0, 0)
```